# PHP do something after 3 post requests was sent

Tags: php, json, post

I'm making a data acquisition project where in 3 devices will be sync to send a post request at the same time to a web server. Since the data from these devices should have same time with each other, I want to wait for 3 post requests (from 3 devices) and create a JSON object containing the data from those 3 different devices.

Any thoughts on how will I be able to do this? thanks for any help!

---

### Javascript for creating random data

this part of the code will be executed when I press a button

```
$.post('plot.php', {micro: "YUN3",acc: data_string3, gyro: gyro1, mag: mag1}, function(data){

    //console.log("posted data: " + data_string3 + "/" + gyro1 + "/" + mag);
    x3=[];
    y3=[];
    z3=[];
    console.log(data);
});

$.post('plot.php', {micro: "YUN1",acc: data_string1, gyro: gyro2, mag: mag2}, function(data){

    //console.log("posted data: " + data_string1 + "/" + gyro2 + "/" + mag);
    x1=[];
    y1=[];
    z1=[];
    console.log(data);
});

$.post('plot.php', {micro: "YUN2",acc: data_string2, gyro: gyro3, mag: mag3}, function(data){

    //console.log("posted data: " + data_string2 + "/" + gyro3 + "/" + mag);
    x2=[];
    y2=[];
    z2=[];
    console.log(data);
});
```

### plot.php

```
<?php

$data = array();

if(isset($_POST["acc"], $_POST["gyro"], $_POST["mag"], $_POST["micro"]) === true) {
    $acc = $_POST["acc"];
    $gyro = $_POST["gyro"];
    $mag = $_POST["mag"];
    $gyro_array = explode(',',$gyro);
    $acc_array = explode(',',$acc);

    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($acc_array); $i++) {
        if($i < 49) {
            $data[] = array('acc_x' => $acc_array[$i], 'acc_y' => $acc_array[$i+50], 'acc_z' => $acc_array[$i+100],
                            'gyro_x' => null, 'gyro_y' => null, 'gyro_z' => null, 'mag' => null);
        } elseif ($i == 49) {
            $data[] = array('acc_x' => $acc_array[$i], 'acc_y' => $acc_array[$i+50], 'acc_z' => $acc_array[$i+100],
                            'gyro_x' => $gyro_array[0], 'gyro_y' => $gyro_array[1], 'gyro_z' => $gyro_array[2], 'mag' => $mag);
        }

    }


    //print_r($acc_array);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

the `micro` key is what I used in naming where the data came from, I want to see like if `YUN1, YUN2, YUN3` has already been posted and then I will generate one JSON object from these 3 different post requests.

Comment: Show us what you tried yet

Comment: create 3 different flag and each time store the status of data received from each source. After Check at your receiving side if you got all three request or not using those fag variables. Do you business logic part and reset the flag variables  ( Storage ) and again monitor the flag variable.
There is second method, you can store your post request at receiving side somewhere temporary location and monitor that. After getting all three then you can reset your temporary storage of that post request and do you business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a small database with a column, 
Named "done"  .

Each time a device connects , update this , (add 1)

Before you start your process, check whether this "done"==3(indicates 3 tries )

When "done" ==3 , you can do whatever you want, and make sure you reset it back to zero when you are finished , so you can start next round, or you can just create a new row with 'done'=0